# Which version of TFS should I upgrade to?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am in the process of planning a TFS upgrade for my company. We're currently running TFS 2010 utilizing the Scrum v1.0 process template with a lot of customizations (e.g. custom fields and states) and about 40 Team Projects.

Our App Tier is a virtualized Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 box which is running SSRS, SSAS, and WSS 3.0. The Data Tier is a physical box which is running Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.

I am trying to determine which path to take... upgrade to TFS 2012 or upgrade to TFS 2013. The question I have of the community is, in your experience and/or opinion, what are the pros and cons of upgrading to either of these two versions?

I have some ideas of my own, but I'd like to get input from others as well.

Comment: I don't think there is any compelling reason to not go directly to TFS 2013. The product has been improved, it is currently Go Live, and you'll want to upgrade from 2012 to 2013 eventually anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Andrew. The input is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you will be able to transfer your TFS projects and adopt them to new scrum templates and features, this is a win but not huge. Most important thing TFS 2012 or 2013 offers new improved UX and contains task Board which will make your process more visual than ever. Moreover, you will have out of the box burndown reports and many more. I would say go for it. Make progress!

Comment: Thanks, Vidas. I thought of pro for either version: 
New agile and development tool enhancements to improve project management and development efficiency